# Why does this text breaks div tag? How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

I just think I justify div's width and height and the text will be inside but I don't know why the text goes outside in this case. Why? How to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head>
        <title>Content Area Prototype 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content.css" />    
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="test">      zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is "content.css"

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 480px;
    height: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto-scroll;
    background-color: #212121;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}

.test {
    padding: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;

    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0.3em solid #59922B;
    border-radius: 1.2em;   
}
```

Update: I want the text is word-wrap in div. overflow: hidden not work.

Update: Why isn't word-wrap default?

Comment: I could recommend `overflow: hidden`

Comment: `overflow:hidden` would, however, chop the text off. In addition to looking bad, this could hide important information. `word-wrap` is the better solution, IMO.

Comment: You want sans-serif, not san-serif...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the `word-wrap` CSSproperty ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap))

By adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `.test` CSS class, the text is constrained to the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/K9tmT/

Comment: This works but I don't know why word-wrap is not default. I think it is contained in div so it must be word-wrap logically.

Comment: Wow, you are too fast for me, and even provide useful links... +1

Comment: The default is `normal`. This will only break a word at a natural word barrier - i.e. a space. If you put really long text into a container, there is no natural place for the line to break - think of it. How is the browser to know where it is acceptable to break "zzzzz...etc." The example is trivial, but it could be very important for a long word, and the browser is going to consider text more important than divs (as it should). If you tell it to `break-word`, you're giving it "permission" to do whatever it has to do to honor the container size instead, even if it means "breaking" a word.

Answer (score 3):

the text isn't broken up so you need to set the word-wrap to break-word in the css. If you were to put a space in the middle of that text then you will see it will break up into 2 lines instead. It's the same principal behind how MS Word won't break up a word across lines

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

or

```
 overflow: scroll;
```

to .test
and/or move height and width from body to .test

Comment: That would create a horizontal scroll bar on the div... nasty looking, hard to use on mobile.

Comment: 'Hidden' would not create scrollbar, 'scroll' would. Which to use deepend on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

[CSS overflow](http://css-tricks.com/2833-the-css-overflow-property/) property can be use in this case

`overflow: hidden;` in `.test`

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/EjFL5/